How do I make my psql client version the same as the server version?
I have PostgreSQL installed on my MacBook running macOS Sonoma version 14.5
I installed it using the Homebrew package manager.
I think I have two versions installed:
brew list

  postgresql@14
  postgresql@16

I think I'm currently running the 16 version:
brew services list

  Name          Status  User          File
  mysql         none
  postgresql@14 none
  postgresql@16 started myusername ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@16.plist
  unbound       none

When I launch the psql client, it runs, but I get this warning:
psql postgres

  psql (14.13 (Homebrew), server 16.4 (Homebrew))
  WARNING: psql major version 14, server major version 16.
           Some psql features might not work.

My understanding is psql is a terminal client to access a PostgreSQL database server. This warning message suggests the client itself has versions, so it's a program on its own, not part of whatever version of the PostgreSQL server I'm running.
I've been looking into this, but can't find out how to update and use a later version of psql, to be consistent with the more recent PostgreSQL server version, so the psql features will hopefully work.
Could someone please explain exactly what's happening here, and tell me how to obtain and specify a later psql version? Ideally using Homebrew. Or if no more recent version of psql exists, should I switch to use the 14 PostgreSQL server version? Thanks.

I don't use MacOS, but I am betting that the 16 version of psql is already installed. That this is matter of modifying a symlink or a PATH to have it be the default. In meantime you can use the older version to connect, I have done it many times. The warning refers to features in the newer psql that will not be available in the older one. Also there is a chance that a  system table that psql uses for information will have changed and the older version will throw an error.

Locate both and set up different aliases/functions for them, using their full paths.

@Zegarek do you mean I should locate the file directory locations of both versions 14 and 16 of the psql terminal client, then setup separate alias commands using their two file paths, so I can then run either specific version with a custom command?

@AdrianKlaver Thanks, I've never looked at modifying symlinks before, but I'll explore this and see if I can get it to work.

@C.Ball Correct, I'd go with psql14 and psql16 as aliases. From more recent examples, this sort of thing is pretty common with python on some environments, where plain python and pip point at the 2.x version and python3 with pip3 use the 3.x.

If you want to run multiple versions of Postgres side by side you might want to look at petere /homebrew-postgresql. Read through the Readme for how to use this, in particular with pre-existing install.

+1 to @AdrianKlaver's suggestion, postgresql-common is great (I use it on linux): "For client-side operations, the usual tools such as psql and pg_dump are wrapped to automatically use the right version for the instance they are connecting to, so you usually don't need to do anything special."

On MacOs, I use Postgres.app so that I can have multiple versions. One of the advantages of using Postgres.app is that a number of extensions, such as postgis, are included. It also has a convenient interface for  initializing, starting, and stopping instances.

Thank you for your advice and suggestions everyone.
